# is there any option for private app distribution for android app in google play without EMM(Mobility management)?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I need proper solution for android app distribution as private app in Google play store without EMM.Just like Apple's unlisted app distribution.

My problem is to distribute the android app to specific organization, i found google play console with EMM is available but i don't want EMM. Please clarify, is there any option for private app distribution for android app in google play without EMM(Mobility management)?.

Comment: Couldn't you just email these people the .apk file?

Comment: We distribute our app on a download site and the current version is able to both detect if a new version is available, and download it for you.  I would not use play store unless you are required to do so.  It comes with limitations in your target devices.

Comment: Please read tag descriptors before using a tag. The `distribution` tag does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @RandomLonelyDev We are distributing the app to thousands of contractors who are not part of the organization. we just give the sign-in credentials. How can i share via email. I need to distribute the app via link

Comment: Put the apk in Dropbox.  send them the dropbox link.